# How to tell ASP.NET not to insert in the request the value of a control?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, request

My question might sound strange, however, it is something I need to do.
Consider having a textbox, and you want it not to go server side, that must stay there, in the client, that control must not partecipate to the request.

How to do this?

Thankyou

Comment: Why not just use a simple HTML text input then?

Comment: Normally you use standard HTML controls if you don't want to interact with the data on the server.  You will still have access to the data server side after a post back to the server by using  "Page.Request.Form".  If you don't want the data to travel back at all, don't use an input control or use AJAX to only post that data you need.

Comment: Another work around would be using client side code to convert the delete the item, or change it to something else (eg. Label that looks like Input) before triggering the post back.  Easy to do with jQuery.

Comment: Zachary: I agree about AJAX, but regarding your 2nd idea: wouldn't the label be lost after postback?

Comment: Yes, but so will a HTML control or a Server control with no viewstate.  If the data is need after the post back, you can use a cookie or have the server re-populate.

Comment: A cookie would still be sent with the request. And, the server can't re-populate without the value being sent to the server.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a server control that doesn't post back.  The only way to do it would be to use a `<input type="text"/>` and put it outside the asp.net form.  I can't imagine what you want to do it for though.

EDIT:

It has occurred to me you could also use javascript to move the textbox outside the asp.net form, but leave it as an `<asp:TextBox/>` so you can set properties server side.

Comment: "You can't have a server control that doesn't post back."  Doesn't setting EnableViewState="false" do exactly that?

Comment: Weird.  I know it won't push its updated content into the ViewState (if EnableViewState="false").  But the ViewState will still contain its orginal value?

Comment: No but the value is in the Request.Form collection and can be accessed server side.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for taking the time to clarify that for me!

Comment: Using javascript to move the asp:TextBox outside of the ASP.NET form would cause an invalid viewstate.

Comment: @Justin, i don't think that it would, I have previously had a bug that was caused by jQuery UI modal, which moves whatever you attach it to to the bottom of the DOM.  The only effect it had was that the values were not posted back.  I wouldn't particularly recommend doing it on purpose though.

Comment: I have been trying to do some other trick but basically it is impossible to achieve this without moving the control outside the form... everything comes in the request if it is in the form (html input tags too). However Carson63000 idea seems good... what d you think about it???

Comment: Yes it seems like a good idea, you have a javascript dependency with asp.net already so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 4):

How about deleting the textbox out of the DOM with JavaScript on form submission?

Here's a jQuery example. Tag the textbox with a class, e.g. `doNotSubmit`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="doNotSubmit" />
```

Then make the form's `submit` event remove that textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            $(".doNotSubmit").remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Checked this in Firebug and the textbox is not being submitted. However you have introduced a JavaScript dependency, if someone is running without script, the textbox will still be submitted. Don't know if this is a problem for you or not.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you want to use an plain HTML control as previously mentioned, but this will still be part of the HTTP Request and be available through Request.Form. I believe disabled controls are not included in the HTTP request so either have the control disabled from the start, or disable it via javascript on form submission.

**Edit**:
Worth a shot would be disabling a asp:TextBox with EnableViewState=false, on form submission.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>In the ASP (markup) code of the TextBox, set EnableViewState="false".</strike>

```
<asp:TextBox id="foo"  EnableViewState="false" />
```

When you check foo.Text in the code-behind, it will be the initial value (empty string).

If you don't want the control exist *at all* on the server, just use normal HTML instead of ASP.NET markup:

```
<input type="text" />
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

However, the textbox value is still technically included in the HTTP POST (postback). The browser always sends the form values on POST.

To exclude some element from POST, you can do a selective post using AJAX.

Comment: That will not stop the values being posted back.

Comment: Ben: you're right. I'm not sure it is even possible to selectively exclude certain parts of a page from a postback [except by using AJAX, as Zachary said].